# Hosting NodeJS service application

Tags: node.js, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, architecture

I would like to build a service using NodeJS. However, this question is more of an architectural nature. Lets say I have 2 companies with their own network security. Company A has a SQL Server instance, while Company B would host the NodeJS service application. In order to get data, the NodeJS service has to go to the SQL Server instance in Company A. Is this considered "bad practice"? If thats the case, whats the alternative? As a note, there is also the option of connecting to the SQL Server instance from AWS.

Answer (score 0):

From an architectural standpoint, it's definitely not desired for an application to access a database through multiple network layers (potentially via Internet), because of multiple reasons, like: latency overhead, security (maybe), management overhead (if the DB is owned by another company).

Generally, the DB should be as close as possible to the app, because usually it's the main bottleneck of a system, and it will impact the throughput of the application at some point.

However, the right answer here depends on the requirements of your app. If the traffic volumes are not very big and the performance hit is acceptable, then you can use that approach (with all pros and cons it may have)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not do the same. You may setup a replica of Database on your application network. To sync the replica, you may setup VPN connection.